# How to stop sys from changing USB SSD provisioning_mode from unmap to full in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: usb, 22.04, ssd

I set USB provisioning_mode to unmap to allow TRIM discard for an external USB SSD that supports TRIM. The system reverts to provisioning_mode full after reboot.
TRIM works great with provisioning_mode set to unmap, so that I can manually TRIM a partition or entire drive when I want to. I have more than one etc/udev/rules.d files -
10-uas-discard.rules, 10-trim.rules, 50-usb-ssd-trim.rules & 90-usb-discard.rules - all contain the exact same data - ACTION=="add|change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="174c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="55aa, SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", ATTR{provisioning_mode}="unmap"

Is there any way to prevent this? Am I missing something?

ASMedia chipset:

[image: ASMedia chipset]

Drive stats:

[image: drive stats]

`fstab` :

[image: fstab]

USB udev rules:

[image: USB UDEV Rules]

provisioning_mode location:

[image: provisioning_mode location]

More TRIM data:

[image: more TRIM data]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ACTION=="add|change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="174c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="55aa, SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", ATTR{provisioning_mode}="unmap"
```

Use these 2 lines:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="174c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="55aa", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", RUN+="/usr/bin/sh -c 'sleep 1 && udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=scsi_disk'"
ACTION=="change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="174c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="55aa", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", ATTR{provisioning_mode}="unmap"
```

This is a dirty workaround, but it works